# R dataframe/ lapply(): get rid of rows with particular values in columns containing particular strings, while keeping everything else?

Tags: r, lapply, data-cleaning, data-wrangling, grepl

I have 16 dataframes I am trying to quality check and delete poor quality rows in R. I already know of lapply() and have used it for simpler wrangling problems to apply the same thing to all my dataframes at once, but for whatever reason I'm having a mental block currently.

The format of each ***individual*** dataframe is like so, where every other column contains a "flags" column. The flags column contains strings of values. If any of the values in the string are a 4, I want to filter those rows out of the dataframe.

```
head(df)

timestamp    wind_speed_max wind_speed_max_flags   wind_speed_mean
1            UTC meters per second                  NAN meters per second
2    data logger   Airmar WS-200WX                  NAN   Airmar WS-200WX
3 6/2/2015 15:46               7.6              1 1 4 1              5.12
4 6/2/2015 16:01               7.2              1 1 1 1              5.16
5 6/2/2015 16:16               8.1              1 1 1 1              5.97
6 6/2/2015 16:31               8.5              1 1 1 1             5.909
  wind_speed_mean_flags wind_direction_mean wind_direction_mean_flags
1                   NAN             degrees                       NAN
2                   NAN     Airmar WS-200WX                       NAN
3               1 1 1 1               57.14                   1 2 1 2
4               1 1 1 1               61.64                   1 2 1 4
5               1 1 1 1                  68                   1 2 1 2
6               4 1 1 1               73.14                   1 2 1 2
```

I know I can try to grep("flags") for the column names, and I also think I could use a similar grep method to filter out the strings containing a 4? Perhaps using some Boolean operators. But I am struggling to piece all of this together to retain the rest of the data, and to ideally perform this at the same time for all 16 dataframes for example `lapply(df_list, function(x) <insert code that can filter out flags with 4s for each x dataframe>)`

Comment: Just posted an answer, but I didn't test as your sample data is in an annoying-to-import format due to all the spaces and such in the data. If you share `dput(head(df))` that would provide copy/pasteable code to provide an exact replica of the head of your `df`, and make testing my answer much easier :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by writing code to filter one data frame - we'll look at the columns that include "flags" in the name and grep for "4". Then we'll use `rowSums` to count the number of 4s in each row, keeping only rows with 4 count == 0.

```
# count the number of 4s in each row of "flag" cols of `df`
count_4 = df[grepl("flags", names(df))] |>
  sapply(grepl, pattern = "4") |>
  rowSums(na.rm = TRUE)
```

Putting it in `lapply`:

```
modified_data_list = lapply(data_list, function(df) {
  count_4 = df[grepl("flags", names(df))] |>
    sapply(grepl, pattern = "4") |>
    rowSums(na.rm = TRUE)
  df[count_4 == 0, ]
})
```